# Creating responsive card elements with static ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to create card elements as follows. But these elements should not change their ratio on all devices. [image: screenshot]

Here is my bunch of code for one of the card element:

```css
.attendants-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
}

.card .img-container {
  background-color: #e2ecff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="attendants-section" data-anchor="attendants">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="replace-img">
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
        <p>Sənin şəklin burada</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="attendant-name">Steve Jobs</h3>
      <span class="attendant-highschool">Stanford University, Computer Science</span><br>
      <a href="kamranmzam@code.edu.az" class="attendant-email">kamranmzam@code.edu.az</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal you could help me to do this task, instead of finding my mistake, man :)

Comment: Try my answer .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a fixed width then use `px` not `%` in `width` value. Because `%` value takes cards width according to screen size.

Try below code or see live demo here at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjnb91as/)

```css
.attendants-container {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-body{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.card .img-container {
  background-color: #e2ecff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="attendants-section" data-anchor="attendants">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="replace-img">
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
        <p>Sənin şəklin burada</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="attendant-name">Steve Jobs</h3>
      <span class="attendant-highschool">Stanford University, Computer Science</span><br>
      <a href="kamranmzam@code.edu.az" class="attendant-email">kamranmzam@code.edu.az</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to keep their width and height static, but change (maximize, or minimize) responsively

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use card-deck in bootstrap which will take a group of cards in the same ratio The example code is this you can try this concept in respective of your problem

> 

```
<div class="card-deck">
 <div class="card">
<img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
</div>
```

For reference see this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/

Answer (score 0):

I've used such method with jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  let cardImageWidth = $(".img-container").width();
  $(".img-container").css("height", cardImageWidth);
});
```

This method keeps 1:1 ratio between image width and height :)